# TypeError: watcher.on(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, chokidar

I get this error when running the below code. I am not sure what could be wrong with the code?

**TypeError: watcher.on(...) is not a function**

```js
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
var chokidar = require('chokidar');



var watcher = chokidar.watch('C:/myproject/instances/b53pd4574z8pe9x793go', { ignored: /^\./, persistent: true });

watcher
    .on('add', function (path) { console.log('File', path, 'has been added'); })


    console.log(`start doing something now when a file has been added`);
```

Comment: Runs fine for me.  Did you install all the dependent packages via NPM first?

Comment: Really that was strange. Yes I have installed this successfully: npm install chokidar --save I am not sure if anything more should be installed?

Comment: Yes it do runs now. I had to add }); a semicolon there because I have some more code that comes after that so now it is working. Thank you for your help!